# Can I insert a view into a table and add an extra column using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

So I want to take a view and send it to a table but I want to mark the inserted rows with a "Status" column as well.

Currently what I have is the following

`INSERT INTO NewTable (Data 1, Data2, Data2) 
 SELECT Data1, Data2, Data3 
 FROM OldView`

and the result is Data1,Data2,Data3 in the new table. But I want to mark that these were just put into this table. So ideally, the new table would look like Data1,Data2,Data3,Status. Status is already a column in the new table. Any help would be greatly, please ask if you need any clarification

Comment: How is status calculated? Or is it a constant value for all rows in this query?

Comment: Status would be a constant

Comment: @t_wimms what u mean by status would be a constant, is it dependent on anything or does it have a `default constraint `?

Comment: Sorry should have specified. It would just be set to text "AddedFromView"

Comment: That is uncanny, that's exactly the value I choose in my answer!

Comment: The best option to add a `datetime` column to the table with default `getdate()`, having a status column doesn't make any sense, u will have the table populated  with insert or update

Comment: I'm inserting multiple views into this view so I don't want to be guessing where they came from going off the time they were added. 
@HoneyBadger , that's where I got it from! I'm testing your answer now, thanks!

Comment: @t_wimms if you want that `Added from view` text in status column , tha'ts a good and simple solution from @honeybadger.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (Data1, Data2, Data2, Status) 
SELECT Data1, Data2, Data3, 'AddedFromView' 
FROM OldView
```

Of course what you select as data for the `Status` column is entirely up to you.